# Using built in LinkedList in java instead of defining ListNode

Tags: java, methods, linked-list

I want to merge two sorted linked-lists (21 leetcode) but I don't want to define ListNode. I need to use LinkedList which is defined in Java and I think its methods are enough for solving any problem about it. ( I am very new in leetcode and I don't know why ListNode is defined at the top of the code in leetcode, when we already have it in Java). Anyway, I created two linked lists and sorted them. Now I need to create another node as tempNode and currentNode for merging these two sorted linked lists. Would you please help me with that?

```
ListNode temp_Node= new ListNode(0);

ListNode current_Node= temp_Node;
```

Also I dont know how to use val like

```java
while (list1 != null && list2 != null) {
    if (list1.val < list2.val) {
        current_Node.next = list1;
        list1 = list1.next;
    }
}
```

Would you please help me? Here is my code.

```
package MergeTwoSortedLists;

     import java.util.ArrayList;
     import java.util.Arrays;
     import java.util.Collections;
     import java.util.Comparator;
     import java.util.LinkedList;
     import java.util.Scanner;

     public class Driver
     {
         public static void main(String[] args)
        {
          Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
          String str1= scanner.nextLine();
          String str2= scanner.nextLine();
       
          String[] str_arr1=str1.split(" ");;
          String[] str_arr2=str2.split(" ");`
          LinkedList<String> lnk_List3= new LinkedList<String>();
          LinkedList<String> lnk_List4= new LinkedList<String>();
          for (int i=0; i<str_arr1.length; i++) {
             lnk_List3.add(str_arr1[i]);
          }
          for(int i=0; i<str_arr2.length; i++) {
            lnk_List4.add(str_arr2[i]);
          }
          Collections.sort(lnk_List1);
          Collections.sort(lnk_List2);
       }
     }
```

Thank you.

Comment: To merge the 2 lists into a new one, loop through them, comparing elements and only add the greater of the 2 to the new list. Repeat until you've gone to the end of each list. Be sure to handle the case of different length lists. Note: sort the lists _first_.

Answer (score -1):

It's simple,
In Case your's input is sorted Linked List then use merge algo (not merge sort, just merge algo) to sort two Linked List.

> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-two-sorted-linked-lists/

Merge algo sorts two list(in your case) to an single list in O(m+n) time complexity. What You are doing will take O(mlogm + nlogn + m + n)

Hence use merge algo and be efficient.

Happy Coding :)

And leet Code is a platform that let's you practice from basics.
They want to teach pointer and merge algo with this question.